# Electron: Copy console output into application

Tags: javascript, electron

I am making a electron application. For debugging purposes I want the user to have access to any message output by the console. However I do not want them to have 
access to the full developer tools. Is there any way to copy the console output into the application? For example, does something like this exist:

```
$(document).on('log, dir, warn, error', function(e) {
    $('.custom__console').append('<div>' + e.contents + '</div>);
});
```

Because this is for electron the solution only needs to work in Chrome.

Comment: If you figure this out please provide an answer because I spent a lot of time the other day playing with electron and I had the exact same issue, running in an linux environment. I could see `console.log` on the renderer's side using the web inspector, but I could not see `console.log` from the nodejs side.

Comment: I just found this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/capture-console, but I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: @NormanBreau, for an electron app nodejs logs, use a logger instead of console like electron-log package. otherwise you would only be able to see logs during development not for the packaged app